# Google search result is displaying ip-address instead of domain name

Tags: nginx, dns, ip-address

I've got a website setup on a static ip address.  When I search for it on google, google has ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.static.privatedns.com instead of my domain name.  ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.static.privatedns.com is displayed in green under the title of the site.

Every other search engine(bing, yahoo, duckduckgo) all have my correct domain name listed.  How can I fix this with google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a permanent redirect from `http://ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.static.privatedns.com/*` to your real domain. With nginx, it's only a matter of adding a virtual host:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.static.privatedns.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://my-real-domain.com$1 permanent;
}
```

You may also find it useful to add your site to [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) and monitor it.